# How to search the location of a plotted dot in a zone in a plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to figure out how to have matlab "search" for center points in my 10 x 10 plot which coordinates are linked to a 10 x 10 matrix. I have a randomly generated 10 x 10 matrix of "0"s and"1"s and each element is mapped to a an X coordinate and Y coordinate in the plot so wherever there is a "1" in my matrix, I am plotting a star in the plot. My question is I want to search through each cell in the grid from (100, 100) all the way to (1900,1900)that I am plotting and if there is a "star" plotted, I want to search to see if there is anymore "stars" being plotted behind this star in a rectangular zone say, 400 x 2000, and find their coordinates. The reason for the (100,100) to (1900, 1900) location is because each cell I am plotting is 200 x 200 and I am plotting the star in the middle of each cell. Here is the code I have to see what the plot looks like

clear all
close all
clc

```
xmin = 100;
xmax = 1900;
ymin = 100;
ymax = 1900;

n=10;
v=randi([0,1],n);
[vx,vy] = find(v);

x = linspace(xmin,ymax,n);
y = linspace(ymin,ymax,n);

vx = x(vx);
vy = y(vy);

scatter(vx,vy, '*');
axis([0 2000 0 2000]);
grid
v
```

[image: wind farm plot]

Thank you!!

David

Comment: Define "behind". If you're looking for points that share a row/column it would be easier to work in terms of the original matrix `v`, rather then the plot coordinates.

Comment: By the way, you seem to implemented a version of the [`spy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spy.html) function.

Comment: @Notlikethat hi so the search function I want matlab to do is to start from the bottom left corner of that "star" so "behind" would be any cells that are "upward" of the first star. In this case (100,100) would be star number 1, (300, 100) would be number 3. so behind star 1 I want it to search the vertical column that's on the left and right of the column where star 1 is and go all the way to the "top" of the grid.